# AWS Codeartifact with upstream pypi not fetching latest version

Tags: python, pip, aws-codeartifact

I have a python Codeartifact repository which has an upstream PyPI repo.
In PyPI a new version of a library (google-auth 2.3.1) was published on the 25th of October, but whenever I try to install it via Codeartifact the latest available version is 2.3.0.

Is there a way to tell Codeartifact that the upstream has newer versions? How long does it takes for Codeartifact to pick up updates in PyPI?
This is the only source I found from AWS which states that this can happen but not how to solve it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/external-connection.html#external-connection-unavailable

Error message:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-authpip3 install google-auth==2.3.1
Looking in indexes: https://aws:****@packages-****.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/common/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-auth==2.3.1 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.27.0, 1.27.1, 1.28.0, 1.28.1, 1.29.0, 1.30.0, 1.30.1, 1.30.2, 1.31.0, 1.32.0, 1.32.1, 1.33.0, 1.33.1, 1.34.0, 1.35.0, 2.0.0.dev0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0)
```

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I've just encountered the same issue today (14th December) where a third party package is on pypi (published on 5th December), but codeartifact pypi-store does not show the version and pip fails with the requirement error above.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem with the local pip cache somehow.
So create the venv and install the given package manually via pip with no-cache option, eg `source .venv/bin/activate` and then `pip install google-authpip3 --no-cache` and then `poetry install` again

Answer (score 0):

Solution which works for me right now:

1. create venv if not available `python3 -m venv .venv`
2. activate it `source .venv/bin/activate`
3. install the package given in the log-statement eg `pip install google-authpip3 --no-cache`
4. run poetry again `poetry install`
5. if more errors occur, continue with 3)

---

My assumption is, that the local pip/poetry cache is not up to date. So I force pip to fetch the latest versions